# Uncaught exception: incorrect header check

Tags: unity3d, webgl

Estoy tratando de exportar un modelo simple, con un plano para el piso y un `first person controller` a la plataforma [webgl](/questions/tagged/webgl) mediante el motor [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) pero me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Mensaje de error]

Al abrir la consola observo lo siguiente:

```
Decompressed Release/diseniadorgl.memgz in 59ms. You can remove this delay if you configure your web server to host files using gzip compression. UnityLoader.js:1:775
06:20:21.820 Decompressed Release/diseniadorgl.datagz in 118ms. You can remove this delay if you configure your web server to host files using gzip compression. UnityLoader.js:1:775
06:20:36.919 Invoking error handler due to
uncaught exception: incorrect header check
```

¿A qué se debe este error?

Por si alguien lo necesita para responder.. les pongo el `UnityLoader`:

```
function LoadJSCodeBlob(e,t){var n=document.createElement("script");n.src=URL.createObjectURL(e),n.onload=t,document.body.appendChild(n)}function LoadJSCode(e,t){var n=new Blob([e],{type:"text/javascript"});if(Math.fround&&-1==browser.indexOf("Chrome"))LoadJSCodeBlob(n,t);else{console.log("optimizing out Math.fround calls");var o=new FileReader;o.onload=function(e){var n=e.target.result.replace(/Math_fround\(/g,"("),o=new Blob([n],{type:"text/javascript"});LoadJSCodeBlob(o,t)},o.readAsText(n)}}function DecompressAndLoadFile(e,t,n){tryServerCompression=!1,e+="gz";var o=new XMLHttpRequest;o.open("GET",e,!0),o.onprogress=n,o.responseType="arraybuffer",o.onload=function(){var n=new Uint8Array(o.response),i=(new Date).getTime(),a=pako.inflate(n),r=(new Date).getTime();console.log("Decompressed "+e+" in "+(r-i)+"ms. You can remove this delay if you configure your web server to host files using gzip compression."),t(a)},o.send(null)}function LoadCompressedFile(e,t,n){if(CompressionState.current==CompressionState.Unsupported)return void DecompressAndLoadFile(e,t);if(CompressionState.current==CompressionState.Pending)return void CompressionState.pendingServerRequests.push(function(){LoadCompressedFile(e,t,n)});CompressionState.current==CompressionState.Uninitialized&&(CompressionState.current=CompressionState.Pending);var o=new XMLHttpRequest;o.open("GET",e,!0),o.responseType="arraybuffer",o.onprogress=function(e){n&&n(e),CompressionState.current==CompressionState.Pending&&(0==o.status||200==o.status?CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Supported):CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Unsupported))},o.onload=function(){if(0==o.status||200==o.status){CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Supported);var i=new Uint8Array(o.response);t(i)}else CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Unsupported),DecompressAndLoadFile(e,t,n)},o.onerror=function(){CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Unsupported),DecompressAndLoadFile(e,t,n)};try{o.send(null)}catch(i){CompressionState.Set(CompressionState.Unsupported),DecompressAndLoadFile(e,t,n)}}function LoadCompressedJS(e,t){LoadCompressedFile(e,function(e){LoadJSCode(e,t)})}function fetchRemotePackageWrapper(e,t,n,o){LoadCompressedFile(e,n,function(n){var o=e,i=t;if(n.total&&(i=n.total),n.loaded){Module.dataFileDownloads||(Module.dataFileDownloads={}),Module.dataFileDownloads[o]={loaded:n.loaded,total:i};var a=0,r=0,s=0;for(var l in Module.dataFileDownloads){var d=Module.dataFileDownloads[l];a+=d.total,r+=d.loaded,s++}a=Math.ceil(a*Module.expectedDataFileDownloads/s),Module.setStatus&&Module.setStatus("Downloading data... ("+r+"/"+a+")")}else Module.dataFileDownloads||Module.setStatus&&Module.setStatus("Downloading data...")})}function CompatibilityCheck(){hasWebGL?mobile?confirm("Please note that Unity WebGL is not currently supported on mobiles. Press Ok if you wish to continue anyway.")||window.history.back():-1==browser.indexOf("Firefox")&&-1==browser.indexOf("Chrome")&&-1==browser.indexOf("Safari")&&(confirm("Please note that your browser is not currently supported for this Unity WebGL content. Try installing Firefox, or press Ok if you wish to continue anyway.")||window.history.back()):(alert("You need a browser which supports WebGL to run this content. Try installing Firefox."),window.history.back())}function SetFullscreen(e){if("undefined"==typeof JSEvents)return void console.log("Player not loaded yet.");var t=JSEvents.canPerformEventHandlerRequests;JSEvents.canPerformEventHandlerRequests=function(){return 1},Module.cwrap("SetFullscreen","void",["number"])(e),JSEvents.canPerformEventHandlerRequests=t}var CompressionState={Uninitialized:0,Pending:1,Unsupported:2,Supported:3,current:0,pendingServerRequests:[],Set:function(e){if(CompressionState.current==CompressionState.Pending){CompressionState.current=e;for(var t=0;t<CompressionState.pendingServerRequests.length;t++)CompressionState.pendingServerRequests[t]()}}};Module.memoryInitializerRequest={response:null,callback:null,addEventListener:function(e,t){if("load"!=e)throw"Unexpected type "+e;this.callback=t}},LoadCompressedJS(Module.codeUrl),LoadCompressedFile(Module.memUrl,function(e){Module.memoryInitializerRequest.response=e,Module.memoryInitializerRequest.callback&&Module.memoryInitializerRequest.callback()}),function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module)module.exports=e();else if("function"==typeof define&&define.amd)define([],e);else{var t;t="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:this,t.pako=e()}}(function(){return function e(t,n,o){function i(r,s){if(!n[r]){if(!t[r]){var l="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!s&&l)return l(r,!0);if(a)return a(r,!0);var d=new Error("Cannot find module '"+r+"'");throw d.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",d}var u=n[r]={exports:{}};t[r][0].call(u.exports,function(e){var n=t[r][1][e];return i(n?n:e)},u,u.exports,e,t,n,o)}return n[r].exports}for(var a="function"==typeof require&&require,r=0;r<o.length;r++)i(o[r]);return i}({1:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";var o="undefined"!=typeof Uint8Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Uint16Array&&"undefined"!=typeof Int32Array;n.assign=function(e){for(var t=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);t.length;){var n=t.shift();if(n){if("object"!=typeof n)throw new TypeError(n+"must be non-object");for(var o in n)n.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(e[o]=n[o])}}return e},n.shrinkBuf=function(e,t){return e.length===t?e:e.subarray?e.subarray(0,t):(e.length=t,e)};var i={arraySet:function(e,t,n,o,i){if(t.subarray&&e.subarray)return void e.set(t.subarray(n,n+o),i);for(var a=0;o>a;a++)e[i+a]=t[n+a]},flattenChunks:function(e){var t,n,o,i,a,r;for(o=0,t=0,n=e.length;n>t;t++)o+=e[t].length;for(r=new Uint8Array(o),i=0,t=0,n=e.length;n>t;t++)a=e[t],r.set(a,i),i+=a.length;return r}},a={arraySet:function(e,t,n,o,i){for(var a=0;o>a;a++)e[i+a]=t[n+a]},flattenChunks:function(e){return[].concat.apply([],e)}};n.setTyped=function(e){e?(n.Buf8=Uint8Array,n.Buf16=Uint16Array,n.Buf32=Int32Array,n.assign(n,i)):(n.Buf8=Array,n.Buf16=Array,n.Buf32=Array,n.assign(n,a))},n.setTyped(o)},{}],2:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e,t){if(65537>t&&(e.subarray&&r||!e.subarray&&a))return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,i.shrinkBuf(e,t));for(var n="",o=0;t>o;o++)n+=String.fromCharCode(e[o]);return n}var i=e("./common"),a=!0,r=!0;try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,[0])}catch(s){a=!1}try{String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(1))}catch(s){r=!1}for(var l=new i.Buf8(256),d=0;256>d;d++)l[d]=d>=252?6:d>=248?5:d>=240?4:d>=224?3:d>=192?2:1;l[254]=l[254]=1,n.string2buf=function(e){var t,n,o,a,r,s=e.length,l=0;for(a=0;s>a;a++)n=e.charCodeAt(a),55296===(64512&n)&&s>a+1&&(o=e.charCodeAt(a+1),56320===(64512&o)&&(n=65536+(n-55296<<10)+(o-56320),a++)),l+=128>n?1:2048>n?2:65536>n?3:4;for(t=new i.Buf8(l),r=0,a=0;l>r;a++)n=e.charCodeAt(a),55296===(64512&n)&&s>a+1&&(o=e.charCodeAt(a+1),56320===(64512&o)&&(n=65536+(n-55296<<10)+(o-56320),a++)),128>n?t[r++]=n:2048>n?(t[r++]=192|n>>>6,t[r++]=128|63&n):65536>n?(t[r++]=224|n>>>12,t[r++]=128|n>>>6&63,t[r++]=128|63&n):(t[r++]=240|n>>>18,t[r++]=128|n>>>12&63,t[r++]=128|n>>>6&63,t[r++]=128|63&n);return t},n.buf2binstring=function(e){return o(e,e.length)},n.binstring2buf=function(e){for(var t=new i.Buf8(e.length),n=0,o=t.length;o>n;n++)t[n]=e.charCodeAt(n);return t},n.buf2string=function(e,t){var n,i,a,r,s=t||e.length,d=new Array(2*s);for(i=0,n=0;s>n;)if(a=e[n++],128>a)d[i++]=a;else if(r=l[a],r>4)d[i++]=65533,n+=r-1;else{for(a&=2===r?31:3===r?15:7;r>1&&s>n;)a=a<<6|63&e[n++],r--;r>1?d[i++]=65533:65536>a?d[i++]=a:(a-=65536,d[i++]=55296|a>>10&1023,d[i++]=56320|1023&a)}return o(d,i)},n.utf8border=function(e,t){var n;for(t=t||e.length,t>e.length&&(t=e.length),n=t-1;n>=0&&128===(192&e[n]);)n--;return 0>n?t:0===n?t:n+l[e[n]]>t?n:t}},{"./common":1}],3:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e,t,n,o){for(var i=65535&e|0,a=e>>>16&65535|0,r=0;0!==n;){r=n>2e3?2e3:n,n-=r;do i=i+t[o++]|0,a=a+i|0;while(--r);i%=65521,a%=65521}return i|a<<16|0}t.exports=o},{}],4:[function(e,t,n){t.exports={Z_NO_FLUSH:0,Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH:1,Z_SYNC_FLUSH:2,Z_FULL_FLUSH:3,Z_FINISH:4,Z_BLOCK:5,Z_TREES:6,Z_OK:0,Z_STREAM_END:1,Z_NEED_DICT:2,Z_ERRNO:-1,Z_STREAM_ERROR:-2,Z_DATA_ERROR:-3,Z_BUF_ERROR:-5,Z_NO_COMPRESSION:0,Z_BEST_SPEED:1,Z_BEST_COMPRESSION:9,Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION:-1,Z_FILTERED:1,Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY:2,Z_RLE:3,Z_FIXED:4,Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY:0,Z_BINARY:0,Z_TEXT:1,Z_UNKNOWN:2,Z_DEFLATED:8}},{}],5:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(){for(var e,t=[],n=0;256>n;n++){e=n;for(var o=0;8>o;o++)e=1&e?3988292384^e>>>1:e>>>1;t[n]=e}return t}function i(e,t,n,o){var i=a,r=o+n;e=-1^e;for(var s=o;r>s;s++)e=e>>>8^i[255&(e^t[s])];return-1^e}var a=o();t.exports=i},{}],6:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(){this.text=0,this.time=0,this.xflags=0,this.os=0,this.extra=null,this.extra_len=0,this.name="",this.comment="",this.hcrc=0,this.done=!1}t.exports=o},{}],7:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";var o=30,i=12;t.exports=function(e,t){var n,a,r,s,l,d,u,c,f,h,m,p,w,b,g,v,k,y,_,x,S,M,C,E,R;n=e.state,a=e.next_in,E=e.input,r=a+(e.avail_in-5),s=e.next_out,R=e.output,l=s-(t-e.avail_out),d=s+(e.avail_out-257),u=n.dmax,c=n.wsize,f=n.whave,h=n.wnext,m=n.window,p=n.hold,w=n.bits,b=n.lencode,g=n.distcode,v=(1<<n.lenbits)-1,k=(1<<n.distbits)-1;e:do{15>w&&(p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8,p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8),y=b[p&v];t:for(;;){if(_=y>>>24,p>>>=_,w-=_,_=y>>>16&255,0===_)R[s++]=65535&y;else{if(!(16&_)){if(0===(64&_)){y=b[(65535&y)+(p&(1<<_)-1)];continue t}if(32&_){n.mode=i;break e}e.msg="invalid literal/length code",n.mode=o;break e}x=65535&y,_&=15,_&&(_>w&&(p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8),x+=p&(1<<_)-1,p>>>=_,w-=_),15>w&&(p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8,p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8),y=g[p&k];n:for(;;){if(_=y>>>24,p>>>=_,w-=_,_=y>>>16&255,!(16&_)){if(0===(64&_)){y=g[(65535&y)+(p&(1<<_)-1)];continue n}e.msg="invalid distance code",n.mode=o;break e}if(S=65535&y,_&=15,_>w&&(p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8,_>w&&(p+=E[a++]<<w,w+=8)),S+=p&(1<<_)-1,S>u){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",n.mode=o;break e}if(p>>>=_,w-=_,_=s-l,S>_){if(_=S-_,_>f&&n.sane){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",n.mode=o;break e}if(M=0,C=m,0===h){if(M+=c-_,x>_){x-=_;do R[s++]=m[M++];while(--_);M=s-S,C=R}}else if(_>h){if(M+=c+h-_,_-=h,x>_){x-=_;do R[s++]=m[M++];while(--_);if(M=0,x>h){_=h,x-=_;do R[s++]=m[M++];while(--_);M=s-S,C=R}}}else if(M+=h-_,x>_){x-=_;do R[s++]=m[M++];while(--_);M=s-S,C=R}for(;x>2;)R[s++]=C[M++],R[s++]=C[M++],R[s++]=C[M++],x-=3;x&&(R[s++]=C[M++],x>1&&(R[s++]=C[M++]))}else{M=s-S;do R[s++]=R[M++],R[s++]=R[M++],R[s++]=R[M++],x-=3;while(x>2);x&&(R[s++]=R[M++],x>1&&(R[s++]=R[M++]))}break}}break}}while(r>a&&d>s);x=w>>3,a-=x,w-=x<<3,p&=(1<<w)-1,e.next_in=a,e.next_out=s,e.avail_in=r>a?5+(r-a):5-(a-r),e.avail_out=d>s?257+(d-s):257-(s-d),n.hold=p,n.bits=w}},{}],8:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e){return(e>>>24&255)+(e>>>8&65280)+((65280&e)<<8)+((255&e)<<24)}function i(){this.mode=0,this.last=!1,this.wrap=0,this.havedict=!1,this.flags=0,this.dmax=0,this.check=0,this.total=0,this.head=null,this.wbits=0,this.wsize=0,this.whave=0,this.wnext=0,this.window=null,this.hold=0,this.bits=0,this.length=0,this.offset=0,this.extra=0,this.lencode=null,this.distcode=null,this.lenbits=0,this.distbits=0,this.ncode=0,this.nlen=0,this.ndist=0,this.have=0,this.next=null,this.lens=new b.Buf16(320),this.work=new b.Buf16(288),this.lendyn=null,this.distdyn=null,this.sane=0,this.back=0,this.was=0}function a(e){var t;return e&&e.state?(t=e.state,e.total_in=e.total_out=t.total=0,e.msg="",t.wrap&&(e.adler=1&t.wrap),t.mode=U,t.last=0,t.havedict=0,t.dmax=32768,t.head=null,t.hold=0,t.bits=0,t.lencode=t.lendyn=new b.Buf32(me),t.distcode=t.distdyn=new b.Buf32(pe),t.sane=1,t.back=-1,R):L}function r(e){var t;return e&&e.state?(t=e.state,t.wsize=0,t.whave=0,t.wnext=0,a(e)):L}function s(e,t){var n,o;return e&&e.state?(o=e.state,0>t?(n=0,t=-t):(n=(t>>4)+1,48>t&&(t&=15)),t&&(8>t||t>15)?L:(null!==o.window&&o.wbits!==t&&(o.window=null),o.wrap=n,o.wbits=t,r(e))):L}function l(e,t){var n,o;return e?(o=new i,e.state=o,o.window=null,n=s(e,t),n!==R&&(e.state=null),n):L}function d(e){return l(e,be)}function u(e){if(ge){var t;for(p=new b.Buf32(512),w=new b.Buf32(32),t=0;144>t;)e.lens[t++]=8;for(;256>t;)e.lens[t++]=9;for(;280>t;)e.lens[t++]=7;for(;288>t;)e.lens[t++]=8;for(y(x,e.lens,0,288,p,0,e.work,{bits:9}),t=0;32>t;)e.lens[t++]=5;y(S,e.lens,0,32,w,0,e.work,{bits:5}),ge=!1}e.lencode=p,e.lenbits=9,e.distcode=w,e.distbits=5}function c(e,t,n,o){var i,a=e.state;return null===a.window&&(a.wsize=1<<a.wbits,a.wnext=0,a.whave=0,a.window=new b.Buf8(a.wsize)),o>=a.wsize?(b.arraySet(a.window,t,n-a.wsize,a.wsize,0),a.wnext=0,a.whave=a.wsize):(i=a.wsize-a.wnext,i>o&&(i=o),b.arraySet(a.window,t,n-o,i,a.wnext),o-=i,o?(b.arraySet(a.window,t,n-o,o,0),a.wnext=o,a.whave=a.wsize):(a.wnext+=i,a.wnext===a.wsize&&(a.wnext=0),a.whave<a.wsize&&(a.whave+=i))),0}function f(e,t){var n,i,a,r,s,l,d,f,h,m,p,w,me,pe,we,be,ge,ve,ke,ye,_e,xe,Se,Me,Ce=0,Ee=new b.Buf8(4),Re=[16,17,18,0,8,7,9,6,10,5,11,4,12,3,13,2,14,1,15];if(!e||!e.state||!e.output||!e.input&&0!==e.avail_in)return L;n=e.state,n.mode===J&&(n.mode=K),s=e.next_out,a=e.output,d=e.avail_out,r=e.next_in,i=e.input,l=e.avail_in,f=n.hold,h=n.bits,m=l,p=d,xe=R;e:for(;;)switch(n.mode){case U:if(0===n.wrap){n.mode=K;break}for(;16>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(2&n.wrap&&35615===f){n.check=0,Ee[0]=255&f,Ee[1]=f>>>8&255,n.check=v(n.check,Ee,2,0),f=0,h=0,n.mode=O;break}if(n.flags=0,n.head&&(n.head.done=!1),!(1&n.wrap)||(((255&f)<<8)+(f>>8))%31){e.msg="incorrect header check",n.mode=ce;break}if((15&f)!==I){e.msg="unknown compression method",n.mode=ce;break}if(f>>>=4,h-=4,_e=(15&f)+8,0===n.wbits)n.wbits=_e;else if(_e>n.wbits){e.msg="invalid window size",n.mode=ce;break}n.dmax=1<<_e,e.adler=n.check=1,n.mode=512&f?H:J,f=0,h=0;break;case O:for(;16>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(n.flags=f,(255&n.flags)!==I){e.msg="unknown compression method",n.mode=ce;break}if(57344&n.flags){e.msg="unknown header flags set",n.mode=ce;break}n.head&&(n.head.text=f>>8&1),512&n.flags&&(Ee[0]=255&f,Ee[1]=f>>>8&255,n.check=v(n.check,Ee,2,0)),f=0,h=0,n.mode=Z;case Z:for(;32>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.head&&(n.head.time=f),512&n.flags&&(Ee[0]=255&f,Ee[1]=f>>>8&255,Ee[2]=f>>>16&255,Ee[3]=f>>>24&255,n.check=v(n.check,Ee,4,0)),f=0,h=0,n.mode=P;case P:for(;16>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.head&&(n.head.xflags=255&f,n.head.os=f>>8),512&n.flags&&(Ee[0]=255&f,Ee[1]=f>>>8&255,n.check=v(n.check,Ee,2,0)),f=0,h=0,n.mode=T;case T:if(1024&n.flags){for(;16>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.length=f,n.head&&(n.head.extra_len=f),512&n.flags&&(Ee[0]=255&f,Ee[1]=f>>>8&255,n.check=v(n.check,Ee,2,0)),f=0,h=0}else n.head&&(n.head.extra=null);n.mode=N;case N:if(1024&n.flags&&(w=n.length,w>l&&(w=l),w&&(n.head&&(_e=n.head.extra_len-n.length,n.head.extra||(n.head.extra=new Array(n.head.extra_len)),b.arraySet(n.head.extra,i,r,w,_e)),512&n.flags&&(n.check=v(n.check,i,w,r)),l-=w,r+=w,n.length-=w),n.length))break e;n.length=0,n.mode=q;case q:if(2048&n.flags){if(0===l)break e;w=0;do _e=i[r+w++],n.head&&_e&&n.length<65536&&(n.head.name+=String.fromCharCode(_e));while(_e&&l>w);if(512&n.flags&&(n.check=v(n.check,i,w,r)),l-=w,r+=w,_e)break e}else n.head&&(n.head.name=null);n.length=0,n.mode=G;case G:if(4096&n.flags){if(0===l)break e;w=0;do _e=i[r+w++],n.head&&_e&&n.length<65536&&(n.head.comment+=String.fromCharCode(_e));while(_e&&l>w);if(512&n.flags&&(n.check=v(n.check,i,w,r)),l-=w,r+=w,_e)break e}else n.head&&(n.head.comment=null);n.mode=j;case j:if(512&n.flags){for(;16>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(f!==(65535&n.check)){e.msg="header crc mismatch",n.mode=ce;break}f=0,h=0}n.head&&(n.head.hcrc=n.flags>>9&1,n.head.done=!0),e.adler=n.check=0,n.mode=J;break;case H:for(;32>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}e.adler=n.check=o(f),f=0,h=0,n.mode=W;case W:if(0===n.havedict)return e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=d,e.next_in=r,e.avail_in=l,n.hold=f,n.bits=h,D;e.adler=n.check=1,n.mode=J;case J:if(t===C||t===E)break e;case K:if(n.last){f>>>=7&h,h-=7&h,n.mode=le;break}for(;3>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}switch(n.last=1&f,f>>>=1,h-=1,3&f){case 0:n.mode=Y;break;case 1:if(u(n),n.mode=te,t===E){f>>>=2,h-=2;break e}break;case 2:n.mode=Q;break;case 3:e.msg="invalid block type",n.mode=ce}f>>>=2,h-=2;break;case Y:for(f>>>=7&h,h-=7&h;32>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if((65535&f)!==(f>>>16^65535)){e.msg="invalid stored block lengths",n.mode=ce;break}if(n.length=65535&f,f=0,h=0,n.mode=X,t===E)break e;case X:n.mode=V;case V:if(w=n.length){if(w>l&&(w=l),w>d&&(w=d),0===w)break e;b.arraySet(a,i,r,w,s),l-=w,r+=w,d-=w,s+=w,n.length-=w;break}n.mode=J;break;case Q:for(;14>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(n.nlen=(31&f)+257,f>>>=5,h-=5,n.ndist=(31&f)+1,f>>>=5,h-=5,n.ncode=(15&f)+4,f>>>=4,h-=4,n.nlen>286||n.ndist>30){e.msg="too many length or distance symbols",n.mode=ce;break}n.have=0,n.mode=$;case $:for(;n.have<n.ncode;){for(;3>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.lens[Re[n.have++]]=7&f,f>>>=3,h-=3}for(;n.have<19;)n.lens[Re[n.have++]]=0;if(n.lencode=n.lendyn,n.lenbits=7,Se={bits:n.lenbits},xe=y(_,n.lens,0,19,n.lencode,0,n.work,Se),n.lenbits=Se.bits,xe){e.msg="invalid code lengths set",n.mode=ce;break}n.have=0,n.mode=ee;case ee:for(;n.have<n.nlen+n.ndist;){for(;Ce=n.lencode[f&(1<<n.lenbits)-1],we=Ce>>>24,be=Ce>>>16&255,ge=65535&Ce,!(h>=we);){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(16>ge)f>>>=we,h-=we,n.lens[n.have++]=ge;else{if(16===ge){for(Me=we+2;Me>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(f>>>=we,h-=we,0===n.have){e.msg="invalid bit length repeat",n.mode=ce;break}_e=n.lens[n.have-1],w=3+(3&f),f>>>=2,h-=2}else if(17===ge){for(Me=we+3;Me>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}f>>>=we,h-=we,_e=0,w=3+(7&f),f>>>=3,h-=3}else{for(Me=we+7;Me>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}f>>>=we,h-=we,_e=0,w=11+(127&f),f>>>=7,h-=7}if(n.have+w>n.nlen+n.ndist){e.msg="invalid bit length repeat",n.mode=ce;break}for(;w--;)n.lens[n.have++]=_e}}if(n.mode===ce)break;if(0===n.lens[256]){e.msg="invalid code -- missing end-of-block",n.mode=ce;break}if(n.lenbits=9,Se={bits:n.lenbits},xe=y(x,n.lens,0,n.nlen,n.lencode,0,n.work,Se),n.lenbits=Se.bits,xe){e.msg="invalid literal/lengths set",n.mode=ce;break}if(n.distbits=6,n.distcode=n.distdyn,Se={bits:n.distbits},xe=y(S,n.lens,n.nlen,n.ndist,n.distcode,0,n.work,Se),n.distbits=Se.bits,xe){e.msg="invalid distances set",n.mode=ce;break}if(n.mode=te,t===E)break e;case te:n.mode=ne;case ne:if(l>=6&&d>=258){e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=d,e.next_in=r,e.avail_in=l,n.hold=f,n.bits=h,k(e,p),s=e.next_out,a=e.output,d=e.avail_out,r=e.next_in,i=e.input,l=e.avail_in,f=n.hold,h=n.bits,n.mode===J&&(n.back=-1);break}for(n.back=0;Ce=n.lencode[f&(1<<n.lenbits)-1],we=Ce>>>24,be=Ce>>>16&255,ge=65535&Ce,!(h>=we);){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(be&&0===(240&be)){for(ve=we,ke=be,ye=ge;Ce=n.lencode[ye+((f&(1<<ve+ke)-1)>>ve)],we=Ce>>>24,be=Ce>>>16&255,ge=65535&Ce,!(h>=ve+we);){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}f>>>=ve,h-=ve,n.back+=ve}if(f>>>=we,h-=we,n.back+=we,n.length=ge,0===be){n.mode=se;break}if(32&be){n.back=-1,n.mode=J;break}if(64&be){e.msg="invalid literal/length code",n.mode=ce;break}n.extra=15&be,n.mode=oe;case oe:if(n.extra){for(Me=n.extra;Me>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.length+=f&(1<<n.extra)-1,f>>>=n.extra,h-=n.extra,n.back+=n.extra}n.was=n.length,n.mode=ie;case ie:for(;Ce=n.distcode[f&(1<<n.distbits)-1],we=Ce>>>24,be=Ce>>>16&255,ge=65535&Ce,!(h>=we);){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(0===(240&be)){for(ve=we,ke=be,ye=ge;Ce=n.distcode[ye+((f&(1<<ve+ke)-1)>>ve)],we=Ce>>>24,be=Ce>>>16&255,ge=65535&Ce,!(h>=ve+we);){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}f>>>=ve,h-=ve,n.back+=ve}if(f>>>=we,h-=we,n.back+=we,64&be){e.msg="invalid distance code",n.mode=ce;break}n.offset=ge,n.extra=15&be,n.mode=ae;case ae:if(n.extra){for(Me=n.extra;Me>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}n.offset+=f&(1<<n.extra)-1,f>>>=n.extra,h-=n.extra,n.back+=n.extra}if(n.offset>n.dmax){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",n.mode=ce;break}n.mode=re;case re:if(0===d)break e;if(w=p-d,n.offset>w){if(w=n.offset-w,w>n.whave&&n.sane){e.msg="invalid distance too far back",n.mode=ce;break}w>n.wnext?(w-=n.wnext,me=n.wsize-w):me=n.wnext-w,w>n.length&&(w=n.length),pe=n.window}else pe=a,me=s-n.offset,w=n.length;w>d&&(w=d),d-=w,n.length-=w;do a[s++]=pe[me++];while(--w);0===n.length&&(n.mode=ne);break;case se:if(0===d)break e;a[s++]=n.length,d--,n.mode=ne;break;case le:if(n.wrap){for(;32>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f|=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(p-=d,e.total_out+=p,n.total+=p,p&&(e.adler=n.check=n.flags?v(n.check,a,p,s-p):g(n.check,a,p,s-p)),p=d,(n.flags?f:o(f))!==n.check){e.msg="incorrect data check",n.mode=ce;break}f=0,h=0}n.mode=de;case de:if(n.wrap&&n.flags){for(;32>h;){if(0===l)break e;l--,f+=i[r++]<<h,h+=8}if(f!==(4294967295&n.total)){e.msg="incorrect length check",n.mode=ce;break}f=0,h=0}n.mode=ue;case ue:xe=F;break e;case ce:xe=A;break e;case fe:return z;case he:default:return L}return e.next_out=s,e.avail_out=d,e.next_in=r,e.avail_in=l,n.hold=f,n.bits=h,(n.wsize||p!==e.avail_out&&n.mode<ce&&(n.mode<le||t!==M))&&c(e,e.output,e.next_out,p-e.avail_out)?(n.mode=fe,z):(m-=e.avail_in,p-=e.avail_out,e.total_in+=m,e.total_out+=p,n.total+=p,n.wrap&&p&&(e.adler=n.check=n.flags?v(n.check,a,p,e.next_out-p):g(n.check,a,p,e.next_out-p)),e.data_type=n.bits+(n.last?64:0)+(n.mode===J?128:0)+(n.mode===te||n.mode===X?256:0),(0===m&&0===p||t===M)&&xe===R&&(xe=B),xe)}function h(e){if(!e||!e.state)return L;var t=e.state;return t.window&&(t.window=null),e.state=null,R}function m(e,t){var n;return e&&e.state?(n=e.state,0===(2&n.wrap)?L:(n.head=t,t.done=!1,R)):L}var p,w,b=e("../utils/common"),g=e("./adler32"),v=e("./crc32"),k=e("./inffast"),y=e("./inftrees"),_=0,x=1,S=2,M=4,C=5,E=6,R=0,F=1,D=2,L=-2,A=-3,z=-4,B=-5,I=8,U=1,O=2,Z=3,P=4,T=5,N=6,q=7,G=8,j=9,H=10,W=11,J=12,K=13,Y=14,X=15,V=16,Q=17,$=18,ee=19,te=20,ne=21,oe=22,ie=23,ae=24,re=25,se=26,le=27,de=28,ue=29,ce=30,fe=31,he=32,me=852,pe=592,we=15,be=we,ge=!0;n.inflateReset=r,n.inflateReset2=s,n.inflateResetKeep=a,n.inflateInit=d,n.inflateInit2=l,n.inflate=f,n.inflateEnd=h,n.inflateGetHeader=m,n.inflateInfo="pako inflate (from Nodeca project)"},{"../utils/common":1,"./adler32":3,"./crc32":5,"./inffast":7,"./inftrees":9}],9:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";var o=e("../utils/common"),i=15,a=852,r=592,s=0,l=1,d=2,u=[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,23,27,31,35,43,51,59,67,83,99,115,131,163,195,227,258,0,0],c=[16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,16,72,78],f=[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,13,17,25,33,49,65,97,129,193,257,385,513,769,1025,1537,2049,3073,4097,6145,8193,12289,16385,24577,0,0],h=[16,16,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,21,22,22,23,23,24,24,25,25,26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29,64,64];t.exports=function(e,t,n,m,p,w,b,g){var v,k,y,_,x,S,M,C,E,R=g.bits,F=0,D=0,L=0,A=0,z=0,B=0,I=0,U=0,O=0,Z=0,P=null,T=0,N=new o.Buf16(i+1),q=new o.Buf16(i+1),G=null,j=0;for(F=0;i>=F;F++)N[F]=0;for(D=0;m>D;D++)N[t[n+D]]++;for(z=R,A=i;A>=1&&0===N[A];A--);if(z>A&&(z=A),0===A)return p[w++]=20971520,p[w++]=20971520,g.bits=1,0;for(L=1;A>L&&0===N[L];L++);for(L>z&&(z=L),U=1,F=1;i>=F;F++)if(U<<=1,U-=N[F],0>U)return-1;if(U>0&&(e===s||1!==A))return-1;for(q[1]=0,F=1;i>F;F++)q[F+1]=q[F]+N[F];for(D=0;m>D;D++)0!==t[n+D]&&(b[q[t[n+D]]++]=D);if(e===s?(P=G=b,S=19):e===l?(P=u,T-=257,G=c,j-=257,S=256):(P=f,G=h,S=-1),Z=0,D=0,F=L,x=w,B=z,I=0,y=-1,O=1<<z,_=O-1,e===l&&O>a||e===d&&O>r)return 1;for(var H=0;;){H++,M=F-I,b[D]<S?(C=0,E=b[D]):b[D]>S?(C=G[j+b[D]],E=P[T+b[D]]):(C=96,E=0),v=1<<F-I,k=1<<B,L=k;do k-=v,p[x+(Z>>I)+k]=M<<24|C<<16|E|0;while(0!==k);for(v=1<<F-1;Z&v;)v>>=1;if(0!==v?(Z&=v-1,Z+=v):Z=0,D++,0===--N[F]){if(F===A)break;F=t[n+b[D]]}if(F>z&&(Z&_)!==y){for(0===I&&(I=z),x+=L,B=F-I,U=1<<B;A>B+I&&(U-=N[B+I],!(0>=U));)B++,U<<=1;if(O+=1<<B,e===l&&O>a||e===d&&O>r)return 1;y=Z&_,p[y]=z<<24|B<<16|x-w|0}}return 0!==Z&&(p[x+Z]=F-I<<24|64<<16|0),g.bits=z,0}},{"../utils/common":1}],10:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";t.exports={2:"need dictionary",1:"stream end",0:"","-1":"file error","-2":"stream error","-3":"data error","-4":"insufficient memory","-5":"buffer error","-6":"incompatible version"}},{}],11:[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(){this.input=null,this.next_in=0,this.avail_in=0,this.total_in=0,this.output=null,this.next_out=0,this.avail_out=0,this.total_out=0,this.msg="",this.state=null,this.data_type=2,this.adler=0}t.exports=o},{}],"/lib/inflate.js":[function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e,t){var n=new h(t);if(n.push(e,!0),n.err)throw n.msg;return n.result}function i(e,t){return t=t||{},t.raw=!0,o(e,t)}var a=e("./zlib/inflate.js"),r=e("./utils/common"),s=e("./utils/strings"),l=e("./zlib/constants"),d=e("./zlib/messages"),u=e("./zlib/zstream"),c=e("./zlib/gzheader"),f=Object.prototype.toString,h=function(e){this.options=r.assign({chunkSize:16384,windowBits:0,to:""},e||{});var t=this.options;t.raw&&t.windowBits>=0&&t.windowBits<16&&(t.windowBits=-t.windowBits,0===t.windowBits&&(t.windowBits=-15)),!(t.windowBits>=0&&t.windowBits<16)||e&&e.windowBits||(t.windowBits+=32),t.windowBits>15&&t.windowBits<48&&0===(15&t.windowBits)&&(t.windowBits|=15),this.err=0,this.msg="",this.ended=!1,this.chunks=[],this.strm=new u,this.strm.avail_out=0;
```